# Weird malloc behaviour

Tags: c, pointers, struct, return, malloc

I have encountered a weird malloc behaviour and was hopping someone can shed some light on it.

Here is one function:

```
struct flowNetwork * createGraph(){
    struct flowNetwork * fN = initFlowNetwork();
    insertAdjMatrix(fN->adjMatrix, 0, 3, 0, 10);
    insertAdjMatrix(fN->adjMatrix, 0, 2, 0, 12);
    insertAdjMatrix(fN->adjMatrix, 0, 1, 0, 5);
    insertAdjMatrix(fN->adjMatrix, 1, 4, 0, 6);
    insertAdjMatrix(fN->adjMatrix, 2, 5, 0, 11);
    insertAdjMatrix(fN->adjMatrix, 4, 5, 0, 5);
    insertAdjMatrix(fN->adjMatrix, 3, 5, 0, 5);
    insertAdjMatrix(fN->adjMatrix, 3, 7, 0, 5);
    insertAdjMatrix(fN->adjMatrix, 4, 5, 0, 5);
    insertAdjMatrix(fN->adjMatrix, 5, 7, 0, 10);
    insertAdjMatrix(fN->adjMatrix, 5, 6, 0, 8);
    insertAdjMatrix(fN->adjMatrix, 7, 8, 0, 16);
    insertAdjMatrix(fN->adjMatrix, 6, 8, 0, 9);
    return fN;
}
```

Notice the second line calls a function which will return a pointer to a flowNetwork struct. Here is the code for the fuction:

```
struct flowNetwork *  initFlowNetwork(){
     struct flowNetwork * N = (struct flowNetwork *)malloc(sizeof(struct flowNetwork));
     N->adjMatrix = initAdjMatrix();
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < NODES; i++)
     {
        N->visitedNodes[i] = 0;
        N->parent[i] = -1;
     }
}
```

Notice that I never returned a pointer (I originally forgot to add it and noticed this later). Despite not having a return the code work perfectly as if I did have a return pointer statement.
Does anyone know why this works?

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Comment: Side note: I think we are supposed to check the results of `malloc` to make sure it succeeded.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260048/c-function-defined-as-int-but-having-no-return-statement-in-the-body-still-compi

Comment: @vbraun: not really. OP is not asking why this compiles, but why that actually does what it's supposed to do, which is even more funny; see my answer below.

Comment: Why it (accidentally) works is also explained in the answers to the question that I linked to.

Answer (score 4):

> Does anyone know why this works?

pure luck. In fact, C says that "forgetting" the return statement in a function with a non-void return type results in *undefined behaviour*, i.e. anything might happen, your program might crash, your house might burn down, your compiler might start its own instance of SkyNet...

The point here is that your compiler probably just does this as a means of being nice. I think it shouldn't. Try compiling with `-Wall`, you will see a lot more warnings.

On x86, this won't happen accidentially. The return value is typically stored in the CPU register `%eax`, and if you don't explicitely return the pointer, there's no reason it should be in that register. However, the last one to write to `%eax` in your function is `malloc`, and since the return value of `malloc`, the address of the newly allocated space, is the same as the return value you want to produce, namely the address of your new `flowNetwork` this happens to work. Shudder!

**EDIT** to be clearer: what I mean with "the compiler is nice" is that it does not scream into your face, telling you you've made a terrible mistake, not that it's magically return the right value.

Comment: It is not UB unless the calling code attempts to use the return value

Comment: @MattMcNabb: pretty sure it's already undefiined behaviour if you don't deal with the return value, because the compiler might do erasing optimization on the values it will never pass on.

Comment: See C99 or C11 6.9.1/12 "If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: I wonder how standard handles situation when return value is __not__ used.

Comment: @myaut that's the thing Matt and I are arguing about.

Comment: Note that it's also possible that whatever is in `eax` when `initFlowNetwork()` returns is *not* the value that was returned by `malloc()`, but whatever scribbling on memory that occurs in the rest of `createGraph()` when using that bogus pointer just happens to seem to work without problem. Finally, it's highly unlikely that the compiler is doing any of this "to be nice". Or on purpose at all.  In fact, it would be preferable if the compiler specifically made this *not* work well when compiling in a debug mode.

Comment: You're arguing with 6.9.1/12 , not me :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, it seems I am :)

Comment: my gcc compiler, on linux, with parameters -Wall -Wextra -pedantic give a warning message about non void function having no return value statement.  So the code does not compile cleanly.  Another case where enabling all the compiler warnings would have saved lots of effort

Comment: As far as I know, the standard says nothing about not using the return statement in a function, it only defines what the return statement does, and its requirements. However, it does forbid using a return statement without a value in a non-void function.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I just looked at some generated assembly, and it appears that without a return statement in a non-void function gcc "corrects" it by not trying to return anything at all, as the stack is unaffected (as if the function were void). That of course would mean that if the return value is used, it would be accessing some random stack value, which is inline with the standard.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning whatever is on the stack which could be a pointer to some useable memory that you're trashing with unpredictable side effects.

Solution: Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a function which is supposed to return something and it contains a local variable.Local variable occupies the top position in the function call stack.When such a function return without the return statement value on the top of the stack is poped.In your case it is N.
Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280877/why-and-how-does-gcc-compile-a-function-with-a-missing-return-statement)