# Missings in a definition of function which returns value - what type of error?

Tags: c, compilation

Suppose I have the following function definition:

```
int foo () {
    int x;
    x = x + 2;
}
```

As you can see, this function is declared to return an `int` value, but there is no `return` statement, and it also does not get any parameters.

Given this  function as defined above,  what type of error does it constitute - syntactic ? semantic ? run-time ? not type of any error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260048/c-function-defined-as-int-but-having-no-return-statement-in-the-body-still-compi

Comment: There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280877/why-and-how-does-gcc-compile-a-function-with-a-missing-return-statement).

Answer (score 1):

This is not considered a bad syntax. It is ok in accordance with the 'c' standard. Therefore it would compile ok, but the results will be unpredictable.

As mentioned in comments, it is just bad programming. Modern compilers can detect such common issues with the programs. So, with `gcc -Wall` you can get the following diagnostics for missing return statement (control reaches ...) and uninitialized variable.

```
%> gcc a.c -Wall
 a.c: In function 'foo':
 a.c:1:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  int foo () { int x; x=x+2;}
  ^~~
 a.c:1:22: warning: 'x' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
  int foo () { int x; x=x+2;}
                      ~^~~~
 a.c:1:18: note: 'x' was declared here
  int foo () { int x; x=x+2;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither. It is valid C but undefined behavior if the returned value is used by the caller. The C standard 6.9.1/12 (semantics) says:

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
>   the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: The behaviour is not undefined. Only if the return value is used.

Comment: Would you say, however, that the reason for this undefined behavior will be discovered during semantic analysis ?

Comment: @galik no. It is neither. A program having a function like that is a  correct program for as long as the nonexistent return value is ignored.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: A program having a function like that and that ignores the return value (and that has no other defects per the C standard) will be **accepted** by a conforming C implementation, but that does not make it **correct**. To be correct, a program must conform to its specification. That is, it must correctly perform whatever tasks are required of it and satisfy any other requirements (such as constraints on time and space, possibly constraints on verifiability, and so on).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Yes, the standard does define it, and the definition is not limited to satisfying the C standard’s syntax and constraints but that it be “correct in all other aspects.” Lest you think those “**all** other aspects” are limited to the contents of the standard, it goes on to say “operating on correct data,” which is clearly outside the source code of the program itself, both in syntax and semantics. So a “correct program” must truly be correct in **all** other aspects, including the expectations of its specification.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: It any case, it is wrong to say a program does not have a semantic error just because it does not violate any constraint of the C standard or because a compiler does not diagnose a problem. If a program’s source code does not mean what its author intended it to mean, the author made a semantic error. A program that prints the sum of two numbers because the author typed '+' when they intended to type '*' has a semantic error.

Answer (score 0):

When the meaning of a program is not what was intended, it is a semantic error.

First, let us correct the function so it initializes `x`:

```
int foo(void)
{
    int x = 0;
    x = x + 2;
}
```

Second, let us suppose the return value of the function is used somewhere. Then C 6.9.1 12 tells us:

> Unless otherwise specified, if the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

If we further presume that the author did not intend to write a program with undefined behavior and that nothing else, such as the compiler implementation, defines the behavior, then the meaning of the program `foo` is not what the author intended—they intended it to execute with some defined behavior, but it does not, and therefore there is an error. It is an error in what the source code of the program means, and that is a semantic error.

Comment: but suppose other information about the program or its intentions  is not provided  -   is it  necessarily an error which should be discovered during the semantic analysis ?

Comment: @galik: What is “the semantic analysis”? A compiler might or might not diagnose the issue.

Comment: @ Eric Postpischil I mean theoretically. Suppose we only know that the way of defining the function above is false. Is it  necessarily  a semantic error ?

Comment: @galik: I do not know what “the way of defining the function above is false” means. Statements are true or false. Ways of defining things are not true or false. If the function does not do what it was intended to do, it is an error. There are formal mathematical/logical systems for verifying that programs conform to specifications, and this function might be proven, in such a system, to fail to comply to its specification.

Comment: @galik: Some compilers will warn when compiling that function, depending on settings. From the source code of the function alone, a compiler cannot determine there is an error, as leaving a function without returning a value is permitted. A compiler could detect the error when the function is used, if both the use and the function definition are visible to it. Current versions of Clang and GCC do not seem to do this. Given that, the error could be discovered by good testing. If it is not, the program may be deployed with a bug.

Comment: @ Eric Postpischil so in this case , it is not necessarily a semantic issue ?

Comment: @galik: Semantics is the branch of linguistics and logic concerned with meaning. A program’s source code is a sequence of symbols (text) that has some meaning. if the meaning is not what the author intended, then there is an error in meaning, which is an error in semantics. Computers are not able to detect all semantic errors, so the fact that a computer fails to diagnose a semantic error does not mean an error is not present. If you are working with some formal definition of semantics, as in a theoretical computer science class, then you will have to specify the definition you are using.

Comment: to sum up, what type of error it could be: semantic error?  run time error ? or maybe not error ? if I have no indication that the nonexistent return value is really ignored - then I can not determine what type of error it constitutes ?