# why do i get 6 from default statement if my input was another character other than (+, -, *, /)

Tags: c, switch-statement, case

```
#include <stdio.h>
int calculator(int num1,int num2, char p)
{
    switch(p)
    {
        case '+':
            return num1+num2;
        case '-':
            return num1-num2;
        case '*':
            return num1*num2;
        case '/':
            return num1/num2;
        default:
            printf("Error\n");
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int num1,num2,answer=0;
    char p;
    while(1)
    {
        answer=0;
        printf("Enter 2 numbers\n");
        scanf("%d%d",&num1,&num2);
        printf("Enter the operator\n");
        scanf(" %c",&p);
        answer=calculator(num1,num2,p);
        printf("the answer is %d\n",answer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get 6 every time the default statement is executed no matter the input
this is my input
(
Enter 2 numbers
first number  4
second number 8
Enter the operator
operator      H
)
the output
(
Error
the answer is 6
)

Comment: Since there's no `return` statement in the default case, or at the end of the function, you're picking up random garbage from the return value register.  Add a `return` statement.

Comment: If you are compiling with gcc or clang, be sure to compile with options `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`. Then you won't have this problem.

Comment: BTW, it is not a *total* coincidence that you get the value 6 after printing 6 characters. See [printf return value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf#Return_value)

Comment: What value do you expect??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `calculator` function doesn't execute a `return` for the break fallthrough case. Strictly speaking this is undefined behavior. See [Why and how does GCC compile a function with a missing return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280877/why-and-how-does-gcc-compile-a-function-with-a-missing-return-statement)

Answer (score 1):

It is undefined behaviour as you do not return anything in your `default:` case. Also you need to let the caller that your function failed. You can do this by setting a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) or introducing another parameter which will indicate the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int calculator(int num1,int num2, char p, int *error)
{
    int result = 0;
    *error = 0;

    switch(p)
    {
        case '+':
            result = num1+num2;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = num1-num2;
            break;
        case '*':
            result = num1*num2;
            break;
        case '/':
            result = num1/num2;
            break;
        default:
            *error = 1;
            break;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    int num1,num2,answer=0, error;
    char p;
    while(1)
    {
        answer=0;
        printf("Enter 2 numbers\n");
        if(scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2) != 2)
        {
            printf("you have entered wrong numbers\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("Enter the operator\n");
        if(scanf(" %c",&p) != 1) { /* handle arror */};
        answer=calculator(num1,num2,p, &error);
        if(error)
            printf("Error\n");
        else
            printf("the answer is %d\n",answer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You also need to check if the `scanf` did not fail.

Comment: If you are talking about error checking, when a division is made, check `if ( num2==0 || ( -INT_MAX>INT_MIN && num1==INT_MIN && num2==-1 ) ) { *error=1; break; }`. This is to avoid division by 0 and, if the system uses 2-complement, check that the division doesn't create a overflow. And also check for overflow / underflow in the other operants.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 he can improve his code. I am **only showing** the idea not writing the calculator for him. SO works like this. But you are free to write fully functional calculator and post it as an answer

Comment: Yes, but mentioning it is better. Most people don't understand that a division by `-1` can be a problem, and some don't know that they have to check the input values.